# SRM 469 Round 1 - Division I, Level Three (TheMoviesLevelThreeDivOne)

Tags: algorithm

I am having problem understanding the 3rd test case data i.e.

{10,10,10,10}

{1,1,1,10}

the answer says there are only 3 good assignments i.e.

- 10 _ _ _

  _ 1 1 10
- _ 10 _ _

  1 _  1 10
- _ _ 10 _

  1 1 _ 10

But according to me:

- 10 10 10 _

  _  _  _  10
- 10 10 _ _

  _  _  1 10
- 10 _ 10 _

  _  1 _  10
- _ 10 10 _

  1 _  _  10

these 4 are also possible.
Please explain me where i am going wrong.
Thanks :)

Comment: http://apps.topcoder.com/wiki/display/tc/SRM+469

Comment: I read that but please explain me the above test case data. Why there are not 7 good ways of assigning the movies.

Answer (score 0):

lets take your example:

```
10 10 10 _

_  _  _ 10
```

Initial queue after distribution J:123 B:4

After reviewing 1st in queue (10 min for both): J:234 B:1

Now Bruce reviews his movie nr.1 in 1 minute but Jack is still reviewing the movie nr.2 (10 min)

This means that Bruce queue runs out of movies.

Comment: so much thanks!
I was making mistake. Considering 10 to be time again in bruce.
Thanks :)